# Create an array of arrays

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create an array of arrays to be used in a JavaScript function.

Here is the format of the array that I'm trying to create:

```
[[1,1],[2,3],[3,6],[4,10],[5,15],[6,21]]
```

Here is the ruby code to create the array:

```
total=0
foo=[]
(1..6).each do |number|
   foo.push [number, total+=number]
end
puts foo
```

Here is the output of `puts foo`:

```
1
1
2
3
3
6
4
10
5
15
6
21
```

Any ideas how to output the correctly formatted array?

Comment: did you try `foo.inspect` or `foo` ?

Comment: your code works - you have the desired array in `foo` :)

Comment: Under Ruby 1.8, `to_s` is equivalent to `join`, but in 1.9+ it's equivalent to calling `inspect`.

Comment: This question needs a clearer description of the _what_ (the desired output) and the _why_ (for what reason do you want the output formatted like that?)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand that correctly, you want to output the array somewhere in a document to be interpreted as JavaScript by the browser.

When it comes to using Ruby objects in JavaScript, you can use the JSON gem.

```
require 'json'
#create the array
foo.to_json
```

should do the trick.

This also works for hashes and some other object types.

Comment: The JSON library should be included by default in environments like Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Change `puts foo` to `foo.inspect`

```rb
total=0
foo=[]
(1..6).each do |number|
  foo.push [number, total+=number]
end
foo.inspect
```

Comment: `foo.inspect` over `foo.to_s` is better for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

[You can use `p foo` to print out the array:](http://ideone.com/WsDPMk)

```
total=0
foo=[]
(1..6).each do |number|
  foo.push [number, total+=number]
end
p foo
```

This prints out: `[[1, 1], [2, 3], [3, 6], [4, 10], [5, 15], [6, 21]]`

Comment: `p` writes this to `STDOUT` so it's completely useless when trying to render a web page.

Comment: No one was talking about the web and OP used puts.